# How to close the popup where ever we want

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-4

Here I have a bootstrap popup.It is working properly.It will close the popup when we click on ok button. But I want to close the popup on special conditions.

When the following condition satisfies I want to close the already opened popups.

```
if(x==y){
    $uibModalInstance.close();
}
```

But it is not closing the popup. I am getting the following error on console.

> ReferenceError: $uibModalInstance is not defined

**JSP:-**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">{{ctrl.modalHeader}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
            {{ctrl.modalBody}}

        <ul ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list">
        <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">{{value}}</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
            <!--<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.cancel()"><spring:message code="label.close"/></button>-->
        </div>
    </script>
```

**JSP Dependency is:-**

```
<script src="js/commons/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.4.0.js"></script>
```

**angular controller:-**

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('facilitoController', function($scope,  $window, $filter, $uibModal) { 

if(x==y){
//Here I am failing to close the popup
    $uibModalInstance.close();
}

$scope.open = function() {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: function($uibModalInstance) {

                var self = this;
                self.modalHeader = modalHeader;
                self.modalBody = modalBody;
                self.list = exceptions;

                self.ok = function() {
                    $uibModalInstance.close();
                };

                self.cancel = function() {
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            },
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: Inject $uibModalInstance in the depedencies of your controller (3rd line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use modal instance for close model

```
if(x==y){
    $scope.modalInstance.close();
}

$scope.open = function() {
    $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({....
```

Comment: it's giving an error Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- facilitoController

Comment: angular.min.js:118 TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Comment: it is not allowing var $scope.modalInstance =

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to close popup before it opens so you are getting this error , when this open method is called?

Comment: yes. If I open then It is opening another popup and it is not closing even

Comment: when ever we want to open the popup then I will call the open function

Answer (score 0):

You have injected `$uibModalInstance` into your modal controller, but you haven't done this for `facilitoController`. You have to inject it to be able to access it like: `app.controller('facilitoController', function($scope, $window, $filter, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance) { ... });`

**UPDATE:** My first assumption was not correct, since `$uibModalInstance` is a local, not a normal injectable. So you can simply inject it into `facilitoController`. As `open` method returns a modal instance, you can assign it to a local variable an then close it manually whenever you want. Please note: you are not able to close it before the instance was initialized and the popup was opened in your `$scope.open` method.

Take a look at working example, it will close popup in 5 secs after controller initialization if the popup was opened before:

```js
angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('facilitoController', function($scope, $window, $filter, $uibModal, $timeout) { 
  var modalHeader = "Test modalHeader", modalBody = "Test modalBody";
  var modalInstance = null;

  $scope.open = function() {  
      modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
          ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: function($uibModalInstance) {

              var self = this;
              self.modalHeader = modalHeader;
              self.modalBody = modalBody;
              self.list = [{}, {}];

              self.ok = function() {
                  $uibModalInstance.close();
              };

              self.cancel = function() {
                  $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
              };
          },
          controllerAs: 'ctrl'
      });
  }
  
  $timeout(function(){
    if (modalInstance) modalInstance.close();
  }, 5000);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.4.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="facilitoController">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="open()">Open</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">{{ctrl.modalHeader}}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
              {{ctrl.modalBody}}

          <ul ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list">
          <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">{{value}}</li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
          </div>
      </script>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have done the same. If I done like this I am getting Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- facilitoController

Comment: Nice answer... found the same

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(condition){
      $('#modal_id').modal('hide');
   }
```